# gets not working in C under Unix

Tags: c

I am trying to input a string in C Language under Unix using `gets` function and it doesn't work!

It shows the following warning :

```
warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.
```

If I run the program I dont get the input field.
The code is

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
 int i;
 char ch,newfile[10],content[100];
 FILE *create;
 printf("Enter New File Name to Create : ");
 scanf("%s",newfile);
 create=fopen(newfile,"w+");
 printf("\nEnter Contents for %s : ",newfile);
 //fgets(content,sizeof content,stdin);
 //scanf("%s",&content);
 //gets(content);
 for(i=0;i<100;i++)
 {
   if(content[i]!='\0')
   {
    ch=content[i];
    putc(ch,create);
   }
 else
   break;
 }
 printf("\nYour File Is Created\n");

 return 0;
}
```

Some one kindly help me out with this. I've commented all the possibilities that I tried.
Thank You!

Comment: You *shouldn't* use `gets`.  Type `man fgets` for your answer.

Comment: I am yet to see a warning like `the gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.`.Dangerous?

Comment: @SheerFish Yes, dangerous. It's officially deprecated since the last TR of C99.

Answer (score 5):

raw `scanf("%s")` is just as dangerous as gets() (both are exposed to buffer overflows). You should use `fgets()` instead, which limits the length of the string.

Another difference between gets() and fgets() is that the latter puts the `'\n'` in the string, which while annoying at first glance allows you to see whether the line was truncated. What you should do is:

- Use fgets()
- Seek the `'\n'`
- If it's present, then the line was small enough to fit the buffer. Just replace the `'\n'` with a `'\0'` and you're golden.
- If it isn't present, then the user typed a line longer than the buffer. Depending on the situation, you are or aren't OK with this. But in both cases, you'll have to finish reading the line (either into a new buffer or simply by calling `getchar()` in a loop until you get the `'\n'` or `EOF`) before your next input.

Comment: `scanf("%99s", content)` would be a safe use of `scanf()`.

Answer (score 1):

The first scanf doesn't consume the end of line character -- you can study this by feeding say "foo bar" as the file name.

The next line should be formatted as `scanf("\n%99s", content);`
 - note the '\n' in front to read the line feed, and the guard 99 to prevent buffer overflow. Still unfortunately this approach is not sufficient to produce expected results, if one types "foo bar" as the file name. Counter-intuitively 'bar' is read as the contents.

And finally the `gets` suffers from the same problem as the previous ones. (+ the major problem, that it doesn't have a guard against buffer overflow.)

Comment: `scanf("%20s",content);` could be used to prevent possible buffer overflow.

Comment: +1: This answer contains the key observation — that the `scanf()` for the file name leaves the newline in the input for the next read operation (and therefore confuses the programmer who uses line-based input before reading the newline, and it also leads to confusion if the user types "aleph null" as the file name as the word null preceded by a blank becomes the first content in the file).